# What can thrombosis lead to?

Tags: cell-biology, homework, pathology, pathogenesis

I am thinking this question.
Thrombosis can result in

1. organisation of thrombus,
2. sepsis
3. thromboembolism,
4. fibrinoid swelling
5. adiposity.

I fibrinoid swelling (edema) (4) can occur.
Also, I think (3) thromboembolism can occur and also (1) organisation of thrombus.

What can thrombosis result in?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this question. First, you give the answer. Then, you ask the question. Please note that I am a layman in Biology, absolutely no expert.

Comment: @scaaahu this is a homework question. Masi is copying a question he presumably got in an exam and is wondering about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fibrinoid swelling involves necrosis and swelling so no.
Organisation of thrombus refers to some very large space of organising thrombus in different ways - so no, since there is an exact mechanism under.
Based on my interpretation of Robbins -book.

The correct answer is 3. thromboembolism.
Thromboembolism is a combination of thrombosis and its main complication, **embolism**.